# PDO - Insertar no guarda los datos, pero tampoco tengo errores en el php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert, crud

Tengo que guardar unos datos de un formulario en una base de datos mysql.

En un archivo php tengo unos select (combobox) que se llenan con valores de tablas de la base de datos. Creo tener bien el codigo del insert, pero por algun  motivo no guarda nada.

Les dejo el codigo a continuacion a ver si alguien detecta algo extraño, la verdad que llevo horas y no veo que puede ser...

```
<?php

/*GENERA UNA NUEVA SESIÓN*/
session_start();

try {
    /*CONEXION A BASE DE DATOS MYSQL*/
    $servidor="localhost";
    $nombre_usuario="root";
    $pass="";
    $base_datos="aa";
    $mensaje="";


    $conexion=new PDO("mysql:host=$servidor; dbname=$base_datos", $nombre_usuario,$pass);
    $conexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);


    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {


        $query="INSERT INTO tbl_incidencias (id_registro,id_tipo_solicitud,id_categoria,id_subcategoria,id_metodo_ingreso,id_estado,fecha_registro,detalle_incidencia) VALUES (:id_registro, :id_tipo_solicitud, :id_categoria, :id_subcategoria, :id_metodo_ingreso, :id_estado, :fecha_registro, :detalle_incidencia)";

        //Preparamos la Consulta
        $insertar = $conexion->prepare($query);


        $insertar->bindParam('id_registro',$_POST['idRegistro'],PDO::PARAM_INT); //PDO::PARAM_INT
        $insertar->bindParam('id_tipo_solicitud',$_POST['tipo_solicitud'],PDO::PARAM_INT); //PDO::PARAM_STR
        $insertar->bindParam('id_categoria',$_POST['categoria'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $insertar->bindParam('id_subcategoria',$_POST['subcategoria'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $insertar->bindParam('id_metodo_ingreso',$_POST['metodoIngreso'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $insertar->bindParam('id_estado',$_POST['estadoInicial'],PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $insertar->bindParam('fecha_registro',$_POST['fechaRegistro'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $insertar->bindParam('detalle_incidencia',$_POST['detalle'],PDO::PARAM_STR);

        //Ejecutamos la Consulta
        $insertar->execute();
    }

} catch(PDOException $error){
    $mensaje=$error->getMessage();
}

if(isset($_SESSION['rut_funcionario'])){

} else{
    header('location:ingresar.php');
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

    <title>Alta de Incidencia/Solicitud - Modulo Web | Sistema de Gestión de Incidencias </title>

    <meta name="Modulo Web - Sistema de Gestión de Incidencias" content="Modulo Web para Alta de Incidencias - Sistema de Gestión de Incidencias">

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <link href="css/fonts/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>

<body>

<header>
    header
</header>

<!--Navegacion-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Bienvenido(a): <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['nombre_funcionario']; ?></strong>
        </div>

        <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" >
                <li><a  href="panelFuncionario.php">Ver Mis Solicitudes</a></li>
                <li><a class="active" href="#">Ingresar Nueva Solicitud</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><?php echo '<a href="logout.php">Cerrar Sesión</a>'; ?></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>


<!--CONTENEDOR PRINCIPAL-->
<div class="container">
    <h2>Alta de Incidencia/Solicitud de Soporte TI</h2>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>  Favor Ingrese los datos presentados a continuación</div>

            <div class="panel-body">
                <!--FORMULARIO-->
                <div class="row">
                    <form action="altaIncidencia.php" role="form" method="POST">
                        <div class="col-lg-12">

                            <!--TIPO DE SOLICITUD-->
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                                <label for="tipo_solicitud" class="control-label">Tipo de Solicitud</label>

                                <?php 

                                $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_incidencias_muniquel;charset=utf8mb4','root', '');

                                //$query= "SELECT id_tipo_solicitud, identificacion_solicitud FROM tbl_tipo_solicitud";

                                echo '<select name="tipo_solicitud" class="form-control">';
                                foreach($db->query('SELECT id_tipo_solicitud, identificacion_solicitud FROM tbl_tipo_solicitud') as $row) {

                                    echo '<option value="'.$row['id_tipo_solicitud'].'">'.$row['identificacion_solicitud'].'</option>';
                                }
                                echo '</select>';

                                ?>
                            </div>

                            <!--CATEGORIA DE LA INCIDENCIA-->
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                                <label for="categoria" class="control-label">Categoría de Incidencia/Solicitud</label>

                                <?php 

                                $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_incidencias_muniquel;charset=utf8mb4','root', '');

                                //$query= "SELECT id_tipo_solicitud, identificacion_solicitud FROM tbl_tipo_solicitud";

                                echo '<select name="categoria" class="form-control">';
                                foreach($db->query('SELECT id_categoria, identificacion_categoria FROM tbl_categoria_incidencia') as $row) {

                                    echo '<option value="'.$row['id_categoria'].'">'.$row['identificacion_categoria'].'</option>';
                                }
                                echo '</select>';

                                ?>
                            </div>

                            <!--SUB-CATEGORIA DE LA INCIDENCIA/SOLICITUD-->
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                                <label for="subcategoria" class="control-label">Sub-categoría Incidencia/Solicitud</label>
                                <?php 

                                $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_incidencias_muniquel;charset=utf8mb4','root', '');

                                //$query= "SELECT id_tipo_solicitud, identificacion_solicitud FROM tbl_tipo_solicitud";

                                echo '<select name="subcategoria" class="form-control">';
                                foreach($db->query('SELECT id_subcategoria, identificacion_subcategoria FROM tbl_subcategoria_incidencia') as $row) {

                                    echo '<option value="'.$row['id_subcategoria'].'">'.$row['identificacion_subcategoria'].'</option>';
                                }
                                echo '</select>';

                                ?>
                            </div>

                            <!--METODO DE INGRESO DE LA INCIDENCIA/SOLICITUD-->
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                                <label for="metodoIngreso" class="control-label">Metodo de Ingreso</label>
                                <select name="metodoIngreso" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="2">Vía Modulo Web</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <!--ESTADO INICIAL DE LA INCIDENCIA/SOLICITUD-->
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                                <label for="estadoInicial" class="control-label">Estado de la Incidencia/Solicitud</label>
                                <select name="estadoInicial" class="form-control">
                                    <option value="1">Incidencia Registrada</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>

                            <!--FECHA DE REGISTRO-->
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
                                <label for="fechaRegistro" class="control-label">Fecha de la Solicitud</label>
                                <input type="date" name="fechaRegistro" class="form-control" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>">
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <!--DETALLE DE LA INCIDENCIA/SOLICITUD-->
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                <label for="detalle" class="control-label">Detalle de la Incidencia/Solicitud</label>
                                <textarea name="detalle" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite aqui el detalle de la Incidencia/Solicitud"></textarea>

                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                            <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-success" value="Validar Datos e Ingresar nueva Solicitud">

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>


</div>

<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="text-center">Copyright &copy; Nicolás Ezequiel Almonacid 2018 – Diseñado y Desarrollado por <a class="text-white" href="mailto:ezequiel.almonacid@gmail.com">nikos25</p>

        <!--Pasamos el ID del Funcionario Registrado a un input no visible-->
        <input type="hidden" name="idRegistro" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['id_registro']; ?>">
    </div>
</footer>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script src="js/main.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Agradezco a todos desde ya su tiempo y ayuda...

Comment: Te falta esto -> **:** cuando pasas los parametros en tus **bindParam**, ejemplo: `$insertar->bindParam(':id_registro',$_POST['idRegistro'],PDO::PARAM_INT);`

Comment: hola, gracias por tu tiempo, le coloco : a cada uno de los parametros pero aun así, no hay cambios...

Comment: cambia $mensaje=$error->getMessage(); por print_r($error->getMessage()); y mira cual es el error o print_r($insertar->errorInfo()) luego del $insertar->execute();

Comment: Solo me queda una duda si estas utilizando el mismo archivo para procesar la informacion podrias dejar action vacio: **action=""**
    y a tu **input type="submit"** agregale esto -> **name="submit"**

Comment: le agregue el name y funciono!!! muchas gracias estimado....

Comment: ¿El código está entrando en esta parte: `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`?  Intenta depurar aquí lo que estás recibiendo en el POST con: `var_dump($POST);`

Comment: De nada Nicolás, saludos.